# R: remove data loaded by data() within a function

Tags: r, scope

I use a function that takes a dataframe as argument, loads dataset from a package, merge the two, and return the merge dataframe.

```
addCountry = function(df) {
    require(intsvy)
    data(pisa.country)
    df <- merge(x=df,y=pisa.country,by.x="ISO3", by.y="ISO",all.x=TRUE)
    rm(pisa.country)
    return(df)
}
```

Before the function ends, I would like it to remove the extra data loaded in memory by data(pisa.country). But when I run the function I get:

```
rm(pisa.country) : object 'pisa.country' not found
```

I assume that this is because `rm()` is looking for the object in the function environment, where  `data()` loads the dataframe "pisa.country" in the "global" environment.

What can I do to ensure that "pisa.country" is removed from memory after function has run?

Comment: `rm` has `envir` argument, try using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually looking at `data()` documentation gives the answer. Apologies.

> Use of data within a function without an envir argument has the almost always undesirable side-effect of putting an object in the user's workspace (and indeed, of replacing any object of that name already there). It would almost always be better to put the object in the current evaluation environment by data(..., envir = environment()). However, two alternatives are usually preferable, both described in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
>
> - For sets of data, set up a package to use lazy-loading of data.
> - For objects which are system data, for example lookup tables used in calculations within the function, use a file ‘R/sysdata.rda’ in
>     the package sources or create the objects by R code at package
>     installation time.

Not understanding the last two points, I ended up changing my function to do:

```
data(pisa.country,envir = environment())
```